# Addition in hexadecimal

Tags: hex

I may formulated the question a bit wrong. I need to calculate the IPv4 header checksum in hexadecimal with paper and pen. At this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum
on the last example they do it.

I have a bit of problem understanding how they count directly in hexadecimal. When doing it on paper what if I get a number over 15 for example 48 what reminder will I use and what will I write down?

Anyone that can explain how to handle this?

Thank you and sorry for formulating the question wrong but I have changed it now:)

Comment: Add where? In a calculator? In a programming language? By hand?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGK8VyV1gLE which describes the process very well.

Counting in HEX (base 16) is just like counting in decimal (base 10) except that you only start carrying remainders when you count past F.

So in your example from a comment, it's just like counting in decimal with no remainders:

```
 15
 24
---
 39
```

A simple true HEX addition is:

```
 11
  F
---
 20
```

1 + F = 10 = 1 remainder + 1 = 20

15 over 48 is simple too:

```
 15
 48
---
 5D
```

8 + 5 = D no remainder, 1 + 4 = 5 no remainder

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal is just a representation of numbers. In order to have the computer helping you with the addition you will have to convert the hexadecimal represented numbers to a number itself then do the addition and then convert it back. This is not a conversion to binary as binary is also only a different representation.

If you do not want the conversion from hexadecimal you will have to explain **why** you do not want to have this conversion.

Comment: I may have explained it wrong. But I am counting the IPv4 header checksum and then there is a lot of hex a so the conversion to binary would take a longer time. If you check this link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum & in the last example, can you explain how they count in hexa?

Comment: conversion and adding numbers would take much lesser time than no conversion and adding numbers represented as hex in a string. don't worry about the time taken. Regarding your last question: show some source and we will discuss it.

Comment: @user1761911 You don't need to worry about the computer having to convert it to binary - it's already in binary! Hex gives us humans a simper way to visualise nibbles and bytes. The checksum math is a series of additions, ANDs and a NOT which are basic native instructions on popular chips.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this may sound like a dumb answer, but it's the best I can give with the way you wrote the question.

Addition in hex works exactly the same as in decimal, except with 16 instead of 10 digits. So in effect, what you're asking is how to do addition in general (including in decimal.) In dec, 9 + 1 = 10. In hex, F + 1 = 10. Obviously, the same rules of addition apply in both.

Comment: Ok i need this because im counting the IPv4 checksum(check link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum) so what if I get a number over 15 like 24, what reminder will I use then?

Comment: @user1761911 That sounds like a totally different question. So you should probably update it and explain exactly what you're trying to do, and whether you need to do this on paper by hand or write code for it.